# sets or set in news

Tags: tense, present-tense

In the following passage, does the present-simple "sets" work? This is not really a story but news, and I don't think historical present is a good explanation here. Why wasn't present perfect or simple past used?

> Dennis Maliq Barnes, a 16-year-old senior at International High School of New Orleans, told CNN he wasn’t initially looking to set any records.
>
> “As I applied to more schools, as my numbers went up, with the financial aid and acceptances into universities, I became intrigued,” Barnes said, adding that when he was told he was close to the record, he “just went for it.”
>
> Barnes said he began applying to schools in August 2022 and took pride in watching the acceptances and scholarships roll in. “It was never really a surprise for me once I reached that number,” Barnes said.
>
> School officials say Barnes’ accomplishment **sets** a new world record and have reached out to the Guinness Book of World Records to make it official, according to Clark Castle, a spokesman for the school and Barnes.

Source: [CNN](https://www.cnn.com/2023/04/27/us/louisiana-teen-gets-over-170-college-offers-reaj/index.html)

Comment: It might have something to do with the record not yet being official - it's not finalized as 'set' until the Guinness Book of World Records approves it, so the past or perfect tenses might give too much 'finality' for something that hasn't been settled yet.  Just a guess!

Comment: @QuackE.Duck  I thought about that possibility too, but I don't recall ever seeing the present simple tense used that way before. If the achievement hasn't yet been official, there are other ways to express the idea, such as "... might have set a new world record."

Comment: This is nothing to do with "historical present" (that's things like *I was down the pub last night and **this guy comes up and spills my pint**!*). Your example is just ordinary present tense. *That **sets** a new record!* is just like when something makes you say *That **gives me** an idea!* (but you wouldn't normally say *That **has given** me an idea!*).

Comment: With recent news items, it's quite common to use the simple present to talk about the results. It's part of journalism grammar to make the reader feel closer to the action.